# Can display imagemagick version on magento phtml file but cant initialize new imagick('image.jpg')

Tags: php, magento, imagick

Can anyone help me with this? I can view my imagick version on magento phtml file but cant declare new Imagick('image.jpg');

```
<pre>
function alist ($array) {  //This function prints a text array as an html list.
  $alist = "&ltul>";
  for ($i = 0; $i &lt sizeof($array); $i++) {
    $alist .= "&ltli>$array[$i]&lt/li>";
  }
  $alist .= "&lt/ul>";
  return $alist;
}
exec("convert -version", $out, $rcode); //Try to get ImageMagick "convert" program version number.
echo "Version return code is $rcode &ltbr>"; //Print the return code: 0 if OK, nonzero if error.
echo alist($out); //Print the output of "convert -version"
</pre>
```

Comment: What does _"can't initialize"_ mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, i got an error. "Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found"
ive tried to create a sample, www.samplesite.com/test/test.php
and put $ig = new Imagick('samp.jpg'); and no error found. but when i put it in .phtml file of magento, it displays this error.

Comment: can you please help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530130/how-to-upload-image-of-product-from-front-end-in-magento)

Answer (score 2):

Simply having ImageMagick's `convert` executable available on the system is not sufficient. You need to have the [ImageMagick PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) [installed](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php) in order to create an `Imagick` object within PHP.

Comment: Actually, it currently works on normal .php file. The problem occurs when i put it in the .phtml file of magento. It worked before, but now, it doesnt.

Comment: can you please help [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29530130/how-to-upload-image-of-product-from-front-end-in-magento)