# How to upload image of product from front end in magento

Tags: image, magento, product

I'm trying to upload the image of the product in admin panel. It's working fine but now I want to upload the image of the product in front end.

I mean customer can upload the image of the product from the front end.
So how this is possible?

Answer (score 4):

First upload image in media/import

```
if(isset($_FILES['file']['name']) && $_FILES['file']['name'] != '') {
    $fileName       = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileExt        = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fileName, "."), 1));
    $fileNamewoe    = rtrim($fileName, $fileExt);
    $fileName       = str_replace(' ', '', $fileNamewoe) . $fileExt;

    $uploader       = new Varien_File_Uploader('file');
    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg')); //allowed extensions
    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import';
    if(!is_dir($path)){
        mkdir($path, 0777, true);
    }
    $uploader->save($path . DS, $fileName );
}
```

Now save product with uploaded image

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ())) //media gallery initialization
$imagePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import/'. $fileName;
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath,array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'),true,false);
$product->save();
```

Comment: we are using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637495/image-is-occupying-only-in-little-space-inside-box) answer  to upload image from frontend. but we are facing problem in overlapping the uploaded image by real product image.

Comment: please come to chat here : http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42832/magento-discuss

Answer (score 1):

One of the most enticipated and needed things in Magento is File upload Custom Option. As discussed last year at Magento Forum, it is not completed nor tested.

Now, Magento already have frontend and admin part of file upload option implemented in themes. Since backend part is still missing, understand that this still doesn’t work, however, if you’re interested how it looks, read on

http://inchoo.net/magento/file-upload-in-magento/

Comment: the link you provided will help only to upload images through frontend, but we need to upload product image from frontend, please help me .

Comment: You can find some help over http://www.hummingbirduk.com/add-images-to-products-programmatically-in-magento/ . This link will help you to save image in product gallery.