# Image is occupying only in little space inside box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

We are using [stackoverflow links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226332/add-image-from-user-computer-to-canvas/37072954#37072954) code to upload image in a site

once we upload, its occupying only little part in box as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/golden-waves-marble-texture-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html).

But image should occupy full box.

[image]

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:100, height:100}).scale(0.9);
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
```

Comment: why not `width` and `height` 450 instead of 100 while setting it?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Even better, width and height to `canvas.getWidth()` and `canvas.getHeight()`, so if at a later stage someone changes the dimension of canvas, they don't need to change it here as well. Makes the code easier to maintain.

Comment: Agreed @AgataB.. That's more better way.. :) +1 already added and I was the first one to upvote.. :)

Comment: Not sure you guys are developers or stars in Js..... @GuruprasadRao

Comment: Not sure you guys are developers or stars in Js..... @AgataB

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe You are blushing us.. ;) Thanks for the comment though.. :) We are developers with practice indeed.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the line

```
var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:100, height:100}).scale(0.9);
```

with

```
var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00, width: canvas.getWidth(), height: canvas.getHeight()});
```

This is what was restricting your image size. Also, I don't know why you have the scale there - but if you keep it as `.scale(0.9)`, it won't fill the whole box. Instead it will fill only 90% of its width and height.

**Snippet**

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (f) {
    var data = f.target.result;                    
    fabric.Image.fromURL(data, function (img) {
      var oImg = img.set({left: 0, top: 0, angle: 00,width:canvas.getWidth(), height:canvas.getHeight()});
      canvas.add(oImg).renderAll();
      var a = canvas.setActiveObject(oImg);
      var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL({format: 'png', quality: 0.8});
    });
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

```css
canvas{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="file"><br />
<canvas id="canvas" width="450" height="450"></canvas>
 Run code snippet
```

Comment: i dont know why they are using scale in that link , i just copied your code and replaced it  , its working fine. Thanks a lot.